# Changes to DataGridView aren't being reflected in database

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, dataadapter

I have a DataGridView control and a save button. When the Save button is clicked, I want any changes made to the DataGridView to be reflected in my database via a DataAdapter Update() command. However, after hitting the save button and reloading the form, the updates are not there.

Here is all the code for the Save button currently:

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=addtool.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=AddToolToInventoryDB;User id=kanerbw; Password=Rabaraba!11;");
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from ToolTB", con);
        SqlCommandBuilder myBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter);

        con.Open();
        SqlCommandBuilder scb = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter);
        myBuilder.GetUpdateCommand();
        adapter.UpdateCommand = myBuilder.GetUpdateCommand();
        adapter.Update(dt);
        con.Close();
    }
```

EDIT: I had forgotten to set the datasource of my DGV to the datatable. Here's the working code:

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from ToolTB", con);
            SqlCommandBuilder myBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter);

            dgvProductInfo.DataSource = dt;

            adapter.UpdateCommand = myBuilder.GetUpdateCommand();
            adapter.Update(dt);

            dt.Clear();
            adapter.Fill(dt);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has several problems:

1. You are not enclosing the SQLConnection in a `using` statement. You should always use this pattern so that the connection is properly disposed: `using(var connection = new SqlConnection(...)){ rest of statements here }`
2. On the `btnSave_Click` function, you are getting the data again from the database -see the `select * from tbl...` code- and you are populating the DataTable again; therefore, it's obvious that there won't be any changes reflected. What you need to do instead is read the Updated DataTable from the page and use it inside the `btnSave_Click` function to push the updates to the database.
3. Your question refers to `DataGridView` which I believe is a User Control on `WinForms`, but your question is tagged as `ASP.NET`. Are you referring to a `GridView` control instead? Either way, both controls should have a way of getting the `DataSource` bound to them. You should be able to use that `DataSource` to push the updates to the database.

I hope this pointers are helpful. I cannot be more specific given the code you provided in your question.

Comment: Thanks for the help so far. I am working with Winforms and a DataGridView so I adjusted my tags accordingly. I've also implemented a `using` statement. However, in order to initialize a DataAdapter, you do need to specify a `SELECT` command.